# Update one field in SQLite table > issue with arguments

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart

I need to update one field only in my table :

```
  static Future<void> updateType(Statement statement, String type) async {
    await db.update('StatementTABLE',
        {'type' : '?'},
        where: "id = ?",
        whereArgs: [type,statement.id]);
  }
```

But I have this error message :

> "DatabaseException(Too many bind arguments.  3 arguments were provided
> but the statement needs 2 arguments.) sql 'UPDATE StatementTABLE SET
> type = ? WHERE id = ?' args [?, Sortie,
> 56fcb6b0-a283-11eb-a4d4-1ffc954983be]}"

I do not understand as I have well 2 arguments and not 3 ..

Comment: I am using like:  `db.update(table, row, where: '$columnId = ?', whereArgs: [id]); ` And its working. PLease make your code like this.

Comment: It does not worked with var row = {'type' : '?'};

Answer (score 3, accepted):

whereArgs is only to replace values in whee clause. type should be in the map :

```
await db.update('StatementTABLE',
    {'type' : type},
    where: "id = ?",
    whereArgs: [statement.id]);
```